# AJAX Post to MVC Controller model every time empty

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to send some data from a modal dialog to my controller with Ajax. But my modelfields are always null, but I enter my actionmethod in the controller.

This is a shortend version of my cshtml-file.

```
@model anmespace.MyModel

<form method="post" id="formID">
    ...           
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">@Resource.GetResource("MyModal", "Firstname")</div>
        <div class="col-md-7"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" value="@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstName)"></div>
    </div>
    ...
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
</form>
<script>
    $("#formID").on("submit", function (event) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var frmValues = $this.serialize();
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("ActionName", "Controller")",
            data: frmValues,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Sorry MVC/Ajax are really new for me.

Comment: Can you provide your action code as well as a code for viewModel object if you have such?

Comment: Your form controls do not have `name` attribute so they do not submit a value.

Comment: And generate you form controls correctly using `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @class  = "form-control" })`

Comment: I think Stephen Muecke is right in identifying the reason of the issue. You can use `.TextBoxFor` extension method instead of entire `<input/>`. If you want to leave `<input/>` then use `.NameFor` extension method.

Comment: Thx, the missing name was the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you want to bind the form data to model then, the names of HTML elements should match with Model properties.
   *Note: name attribute value of html input field should match to the property of a model.*
2. When you use form and submit button then it will try to reload the page by posting data to the server. You need to prevent this action. You can do this by returning false on onSubmit event in the Form element.
3. When you use jquery, do not forget to keep the ajax call/events inside the  $(document).ready(function(){}) function.

   I have written a simple code which takes First Name as input and makes an ajax call on clicking on submit button.

## Html & Jquery Code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#formID").on("submit", function(event) {
            var $this = $(this);
            var frmValues = $this.serialize();
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                async: true,
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("PostData", "Home")",
                data: frmValues,
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data.FirstName);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<div>
    <form method="post" id="formID" onsubmit="return false;">
        <input id="FirstName" name="FirstName"/>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

## My Model :

```
public class Person
{
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

## Action Method:

```
public ActionResult PostData(Person person)
{
    return Json(new { Success = true, FirstName = person.FirstName });
}
```

## Output:

[image]

Comment: desnt work for me, data is in the `Request` but the model is empty